# Visual Studio Code Integrated Terminal on OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Can someone please post a good source for configuring bash on OSX El Capitan so VS Code can display the integrated terminal? No coding window appears under my terminal tab :(
My VSC settings (which I got from [VSC Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)) are:

```js
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {},

"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/bash",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [
"-l"
],
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you having trouble opening the terminal or using the terminal?

Comment: In the integrated terminal tab there is no terminal coding window at all, not even after restarting VSC or rebooting.  My bash_profile has: export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Have you tried showing the integrated terminal while an edit window is open on the screen?